# How to get RGB values from a video?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

I want to get the RGB values of a video and put it in a 2D array with frames (frame,rgb value) and save it in a file.
I only found a way to get it on image pixles and don't know how to save the array in a file.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("D:\swim\Frames1\Frames1.png")
pix=im.load()
width, height = im.size
pixels = [pix[i, j] for i in range(width) for j in range(height)]
print (pixels)
```

in conclusion: I want to load a video and convert it to an array consisting of frames,RGB is that possible?

I have tried

```
from numpy import asarray
from numpy import savetxt
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('D:\swim\swim99.mp4')
rgb_list = []
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

if not ret:
    break

rgb_frame_i = frame.reshape(-1, 3).tolist()
rgb_list.extend(rgb_frame_i)
print(rgb_frame_i)
```

but it didn't print anything and I don't know how to save it in a file.

Comment: Please do not vandalize questions (even your own), especially after receiving a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Things you should know:

Step 1 - Convert your videos into Frames

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
     -------------------------------------------------------------> step 2 - split  
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Step 2 - Split your frames into B,G,R

```
b,g,r = cv2.split(frame)
```

Step 3 - Save independent frames and convert to a video.